# Why is AngularFire Routing rendering blank pages

Tags: routes, angularfire, ngroute

I downloaded the *AngularFire* seed and I'm trying to change the routes for a project I'm working on but so far I have not been successful. I simply changed '`/home`' to '`/`' and '`/chat`' to '`/selectcard`' and '`/login`' to '`/cardcredentials`' and accordingly, I also changed the names of the .html templates.

Now I receive blank pages in the deployed application. I've poured over the angular ngroute documentation but I can't figure out where I am going wrong.

```
.constant('ROUTES', {
    '/': {
      templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
      controller: 'HomeCtrl',
      resolve: {
        // forces the page to wait for this promise to resolve before controller is loaded
        // the controller can then inject `user` as a dependency. This could also be done
        // in the controller, but this makes things cleaner (controller doesn't need to worry
        // about auth status or timing of displaying its UI components)
        user: ['simpleLogin', function(simpleLogin) {
          return simpleLogin.getUser();
        }]
      }
    },
    '/SelectCard': {
      templateUrl: 'partials/selectcard.html',
      controller: 'ChatCtrl'
    },
    '/CardCredentials': {
      templateUrl: 'partials/cardcredentials.html',
      controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    },
    '/OffersDetails': {
      templateUrl: 'partials/offerdetails.html',
      controller: 'AccountCtrl',
      // require user to be logged in to view this route
      // the whenAuthenticated method below will resolve the current user
      // before this controller loads and redirect if necessary
      authRequired: true
    }
  })
```

Comment: What error messages are printed in the JS console?

Answer (score 0):

When you download the angularfire seed you must do a bower install.  I'm not sure why these don't install automatically given that they must be there for the app to work.